# How to insert to a particular position in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

is there any way to insert ndarray to another ndarray?

Comment: You need this: `a1[0][1] = 9`

Comment: That' an underspecified action.  It can either be trivial or impossible.